# UICollectionViewCell's text is appearing somewhere else when the cell is reused

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm making a timetable app using swift.
I load my data from website and put it on a `collectionView`.
In the first section, I put the day of the week and in the first row, I put the classes and in other cells, I put the data from the web (subject Name, class room...)
If I enter the timetable view, everything is fine at first.
However, if I scroll down and scroll up, some text are printed where they shouldn't be.

[image: First time when I enter the timetable view]

[image: After I scroll down and up]

This is my `collectionView(collectionView: , cellForItemAtIndexPath: )`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("\(indexPath.section), \(indexPath.row)")
    let dayArray = ["", "월", "화", "수", "목", "금"]
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        // Day
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        var titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height))
        cell.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.text = dayArray[indexPath.row]
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        cell.backgroundColor = mainColor
        print("day")
        return cell
    }
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // index
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        var titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height))
        cell.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.text = String(indexPath.section)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        cell.backgroundColor = mainColor
        print("time")
        return cell
    }
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeTableCell
    if let timeTableElement = self.timeTable[indexPath.section-1][indexPath.row-1] {
        cell.subjectNameLabel.text = timeTableElement.subjectName
        cell.subjectNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.classRoomLabel.text = timeTableElement.classRoom
        cell.classRoomLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    } else {
        cell.subjectNameLabel.text = ""
        cell.classRoomLabel.text = ""
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = mainColor
    print("class")
    return cell
}
```

I'm using a default `UICollectionViewCell` with adding a label subview to show the day and class time and using a custom `TimeTableCell` to show the class data.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a different 'reuseIdentifier' for TimeTableCell:

1. change reuse identifier in attributes inspector:
   [image]
2. change your code:

   ```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(yourReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeTableCell
   ```

ps. I suggest to remove the existed titleLabel first and then add the new one, otherwise it will be add again when scrolling down and up.

EDIT

You can 'delete' the titleLabel in two ways:

1. add a custom cell as well as TimeTableCell(different name and different ReuseIdentifier). as you can see,subjectNameLabel in TimeTableCell will not be add again and again.
2. set a tag for titleLabel after initialization, and remove it according to the tag.

   ```
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
   cell.contentView.viewWithTag(999)!.removeFromSuperview()
   var titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height))
   titleLabel.tag = 999
   cell.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
   titleLabel.text = dayArray[indexPath.row]
   titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
   cell.backgroundColor = mainColor
   print("day")
   return cell
   ```

Comment: Can I use a different resueIdentifier in the storyboard?
Also, how can I delete the titleLabel? Is there a function called when a cell is delloced? @CoderWang

Comment: I tried to use different resueIdentifier for TimeTabelCell but I got an error.

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: yes,of course. select your TimeTableCell in the storyboard, and switch to Attributes inspector,  check the row 2, Reuse Identifier should be there.

Comment: change 'reuse Identifier' to yourReuseIdentifier, and then modify this line:
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(yourReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeTableCell

Comment: there's no "row" section in attributes inspector @CoderWang

Comment: @김승수 sorry, i treated UICollectionViewCell as UITableViewCell, check the edited answer.

Comment: Sorry for keep asking. But how can I delete the titleLabel and where should I delete the label? @CoderWang

Comment: @김승수 it`s ok. only wish what i have provided can help you out. Answer has been edited again  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Remove Title Label before you addd it

```
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
     // Here find view with tag 999 and remove it from superview 
    var titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height))
    cell.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleLabel.tag = 999;
    titleLabel.text = String(indexPath.section)
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    cell.backgroundColor = mainColor
    print("time")
    return cell
```